# How do I list entrepreneurial experience on my resume?

Tags: resume, work-experience, startup

I co-founded a start-up in fashion industry, I intend to leave because of financial reason and not having a central role. My work was mostly involved in designing site & marketing.

1) How do I mention this start-up in my resume, should I mention this under professional experience or make a new category?

2) How do I explain the situation when the start-up is a year old?

P.S: I'm applying to another start-up in intellectual property right field. I have B.S with major in industrial engineering.

Answer (score 5):

I would list it as another job entry. For example:

> 2012-2014 Co-Founder, Fashion Tech
>
> I founded a fashion technology company focussed on XX. My
>   responsibilities were YY and ZZ. I managed to (add achievement, no
>   matter how minor).

There is no reason to say why you left. The purpose of a CV is to get you an interview. Once you get to an interview, and only if you are asked, say something neutral like "While I enjoyed founding the company, I didn't like the direction it was going. So I decided to part ways."

Make sure you make it clear you didn't quit because you couldn't handle the pressure, or because you only like starting things, not finishing them (both of which an interviewer might assume). So rehearse a few answers to questions like these.

I can't give any more specific advice without knowing all the details.

Answer (score 1):

When I got my currently job, my boss actually researched me, I had left my own business off because I had never thought to put it on there and had been told that if you have self employed and the like on your CV then it can look bad

My current boss however told me that he only employed me because he found out and to him it showed I was creative and intuitive and that I was not afraid to try something.

So I would say yes, keep it on there.